# Java gregorian calendar and removing time and timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, gregorian-calendar

I have a gregorian calendar that serializes to the string below during a soap request

```
2079-07-07T00:00:00.000-07:00
```

The .NET webservice reads it as the string below

```
07/07/2079 01:00:00
```

Is the 07:00 causing the issue?  If so how can I get rid of this?

Comment: `2079-07-07T00:00:00.000-07:00` looks correct. Why do you think that .net service reads wrong time? I think the output statement just prints it in a different tmezone.

Comment: I dont have access to the .NET code, but you might be right, it may be adding it by mistake, and its not my code, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone might be able to give you an affirmative answer if you tell us which time zone is configured on your system, but I would assume a mismatch in the DST rules.

The JVM comes with its own timezone and DST rule database, while Windows (and .NET) uses a different database. In theory, the two databases should of course contain the same rules, but I have ran into differences in the DST rules for historical dates. I would assume there might be differences for dates far in the future as well.

If you actually want to transport a date value (no time component) over the SOAP service, the easiest solution would be to use the appropriate XML Schema datatype instead of a datetime type.

Comment: This property is autogenerated from a WSDL so changing that isnt a good solution on our end.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DateTimeOffset` in your .net code and it will work just fine.

Comment: Then you need to better understand exactly what input the .Net service is expecting.  Do they expect a UTC value? A local value? Whose local?  What you have is in ISO8601 format, which is exactly what you should be using, but you are passing it in with a local offset.  It sounds like the service is applying that offset appropriately.  So if that's not what you want to do, then don't send it that way.  Perhaps it would help if you explained what this field is representing, and showed the Java code where you are populating the value.